# wp8 can I use IntPtr to improve image processing performance

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have started an app that passes a phone cameras image through several filters in real time.

I can get the data from the camera as a greyscale byte array.  A lot of the steps involve iterating through the pixels and taking local data from surrounding pixels and manipulating it.  Everything works, but the performance on the phones is disappointing.  With high quality cameras we can be talking about an array with over 300,000 bytes in (640x480).

I cant use unsafe code blocks (windows phone wont let you) i.e. pointers. IntPtr has an Add and Subtract method, would I still be able to use this like a pointer if I pin the source array and access the byte info via shifting?

I can't seem to find any good examples of it being used this way (probably because you shouldn't) and see quotes such as "The IntPtr type is for passing around handles or pointers and also for marshalling to languages that support pointers. But it's not for pointer arithmetic." All well and good if you CAN use pointers :)

Is there a better way to approach this?

```
//Crude Example - ignore the fact that this would get out of bounds exceptions etc

public byte[] TakeAreaAvg(byte[] sourceArray, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight)
{
        int size = sourceWidth*sourceHeight;
        byte[] avgBytes = new byte[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        { 
             avgbytes[i] = (byte)((sourceArray[ i - sourceWidth - 1] + 
                                  sourceArray[ i - sourceWidth] + 
                                  sourceArray[ i - sourceWidth + 1] +
                                  sourceArray[ i - 1] +
                                  sourceArray[ i ] +
                                  sourceArray[ i + 1] +
                                  sourceArray[ i + sourceWidth - 1] +
                                  sourceArray[ i + sourceWidth] +
                                  sourceArray[ i + sourceWIdth + 1]) / 9); 
        }
        return avgBytes;
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about windows phone, but... use C++? You could use interop and see if the performance gain outweighs the overhead of interop call itself (or just write the whole thing in native code of course)

Comment: Unfortunately, we're writing this with Xamarin in mind as we can target iOs and android without going native with all of them (except UI). I just didn't want to sacrifice quality for performance.

Comment: All WP8 devices have at least two cores, and your code is easy to parallelize, so it could be a cheap way to improve performance. Otherwise, I don't see how using a pointer could be *much* faster than accessing an array. There would be a gain because you would be skipping bonds checking, but I don't believe it would be a deal changer

Comment: Hi, I am already using multiple threads where I can, most steps have been reduced down to O(n) magnitude. I wasn't sure about how much faster a pointer would be than accessing the array directly, but since it happens so much (due to size of array) i'm just trying to explore all possibilities

Comment: Have you checked with a profiler if the time really gets lost where you expect it?

Comment: Hi, the profiler isn't something i've had to use before but i'll definately look into it now and see if anything crops up. Thanks.

I am currently removing the use of any multidimensional arrays in favour of single dimension arrays, as a small test revealed it was quite a bit faster.